# Updating an item using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I wish to update an item using LINQ.  I tried this query.

```
string option = "new value here";

(jt.SummarySpecs.Select(x => x.DocSpecs)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Where(
        y => y.DelItemID == docSpc.DelItemID &&
        y.ItemCode == docSpc.ItemCode
    )
    .FirstOrDefault().FinishingOptionsDesc[0]
) = option;
```

I wish to update the value of "FinishingOptionDesc," this is a collection of string values but I only wish to update the 1st one.

But the code above is not working.

The classes attributes:

```
"SummarySpecs.cs"
    public DocSpec[] DocSpecs { get; set; }

"DocSpecs.cs"
    public string[] FinishingOptionsDesc { get; set; }
```

---

My only concern is to update the FinishingOptionDesc 1st string.

thanks

Comment: did you try removing the outermost parentheses?... and explain a little more...

Comment: Try removing your first 'FirstOrDefault' clause.

Comment: yes caerolus, but still it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code which prevents this snippet from working is the `Select(/*...*/)` method. This creates a new reference and takes you execution out of the expression tree back to the object context.

You have to write it like this:

```
jt.SummarySpecs
.Where(y => 
    y.DocSpecs.First().DelItemID = docSpc.DelItemID
    && y.DocSpecs.First().ItemCode == docSpc.ItemCode)
.First().DocSpecs.First().FinishingOptionsDesc.First() = option;
```

It is not very beautyfull, but the only way to achieve your goal.
For more pretty code use the QES:

```
(from item in jt.SummarySpecs
let searchItem = item.DocSpecs.First()
where searchItem.DelItemID = docSpc.DelItemID
&& searchItem.ItemCode = docSpc.ItemCode
select item)
.First().DocSpecs.First().FinishinOptionsDesc.First() = option;
```

This way ensures, that you "do not leave the expression tree" until the end of your statement, so you can modify your reference directly, without loosing the given data.

Comment: tried the code above but I got an error.  'y' doesn't exist in the current context. this part of the code "y.First().DocSpecs.First()"

Comment: tried this once as well

jt.SummarySpecs
                            .Where(y =>
                                y.First().DocSpecs.First().DelItemID = docSpc.DelItemID
                                && y.First().DocSpecs.First().ItemCode == docSpc.ItemCode)
                            .First().DocSpecs.First().FinishingOptionsDesc.First() = option;
                            
but got an error.   y.first() "doesn't contain a definition..."

Comment: not working.... 
Doesn't contain a definition for 'DocSpecs' and no existing method for...... for this line of code .First().DocSpecs.First().FinishinOptionsDesc.First() = option;

Comment: Please specify your question... those errors you are posting are the results of missing information, I have tried to help you as good as I can with the given information, please provide us your classes etc for better answers

Comment: updated code above... added the classes involved in the query. thanks